# CRM2011 Solution import fails. Where to find error report

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to import a solution after deleting Custom Ribbon button in customization.xml. But it's failing while importing without showing any error information. Where can I get this error info.

Comment: Settings -> System Jobs?

Comment: When you import it, do you not get an option to download the log file? Is there anything in there at all?

Answer (score 3):

Normally when an import fails it will give you the option to download a log file, if you open it in Excel the second tab will show the error status against individual components.

If you can't get the log file from here, an alternative is to look in the ImportJob view. This has a 'data' column which has the same information as the import log file does.